Execution Plan Estimates vs Actuals with Inequality Filters
I have the following SQL query:
declare @p1 INT = 20240703;
declare @p2 INT = 20240703;
declare @p3 NVARCHAR(50) = N'USA';

SELECT R.taxareaid, R.filtertypes
FROM region R
JOIN country C ON R.countryid = C.countryid 
where C.name = @p3
and  R.effdate <= @p1 AND R.expdate >= @p2
ORDER BY R.taxareaid 
OPTION (RECOMPILE);

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1FTNkXHkx
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Region](
    [regionId] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [taxAreaId] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [effDate] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [expDate] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [countryId] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [mainDivisionId] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [subDivisionId] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [cityId] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [postalCodeId] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [cityCompressedId] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [subDivCompressedId] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [filterTypes] [numeric](32, 0) NOT NULL,
    [updateId] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT pk_region PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [regionId] ASC
)

Problem:

Execution Plan Estimates: When I look at the execution plan, I notice that the estimates are much smaller than the actual rows processed. Although I'm using OPTION (RECOMPILE) to prevent parameter sniffing, I'm still not getting accurate estimates. I’ve also updated statistics on the region table using a full scan, but the estimates are still incorrect.

TempDB Spill: The query is leading to a spill to TempDB during sorting.


What I’ve Tried:

Updated Statistics: I performed a full scan to update statistics on the region table.
Indexes: I created an index on region(taxareaid) and a composite index on (countryid, effdate, expdate, taxareaid), but I am still seeing sorting in the execution plan.

My Questions:

How can I get more accurate execution plan estimates to avoid the TempDB spill during sorting?
How can I avoid the sorting operation entirely? Are there other strategies I can try, given that indexing doesn’t seem to resolve the issue?


To do literally what is asked in the question, you need these two secondary indexes (and no others):
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX 
    [UQ dbo.Country name] 
ON 
    dbo.Country ([name]);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX 
    [IX dbo.Region countryId, taxAreaId (effDate, expDate, filterTypes)] 
ON 
    dbo.Region (countryId, taxAreaId) 
INCLUDE 
    (effDate, expDate, filterTypes);

Correcting the data types of the variables to match the table:
DECLARE 
    @p1 numeric(8, 0) = 20240703,
    @p2 numeric(8, 0) = 20240703,
    @p3 nvarchar(50) = N'USA';

SELECT 
    R.taxAreaId, 
    R.filterTypes
FROM dbo.Region AS R
JOIN dbo.Country AS C 
    ON C.countryId = R.countryId
WHERE 
    C.[name] = @p3
    AND R.effDate <= @p1 
    AND R.expDate >= @p2
ORDER BY
    R.taxAreaId ASC;

The plan is:

The unique index on Country is needed to ensure the name lookup is guaranteed to produce at most one row.
The index on Region allows a seek on countryId, returning rows in taxAreaId order.
That's the most we can do with an unfiltered b-tree index. The other predicates on effDate and expDate cannot be used to seek while also preserving taxAreaId order. So, these two predicates will be applied as residual tests on all rows matching the countryId.
You may or may not find this plan performs better in practice than the one with the sort.
Notice you do not need the RECOMPILE hint above. Cardinality estimates may or may not be better. They don't matter for this plan shape. You seem to always want the nested loops apply and no sort. Nothing depends on the cardinality estimate from the Region table.
It makes little sense to use numeric as the data type for all columns on a table, especially those presumably storing dates. You won't always see a type conversion warning because SQL Server tries hard to engineer a seek even when the programmer has been sloppy with data types. But these are separate issues that you did not ask about.

Great information , thank you

You can try rewriting the query by factoring out the part that selects the countryid into a separate query. This may help improve cardinality estimates:
declare @p1 [numeric](18, 0) = 20240703;
declare @p2 [numeric](18, 0) = 20240703;
declare @p3 NVARCHAR(50) = N'United States';

declare @countryid int = (select countryid from country C where C.name = @p3);

SELECT R.taxareaid, R.filtertypes
FROM region R
where countryid =  @countryid
    and  R.effdate <= @p1 AND R.expdate >= @p2
ORDER BY R.taxareaid 
OPTION (RECOMPILE);

To avoid sorting, you create an index with taxAreaId as the leading key column:
CREATE INDEX IX_taxAreaId
ON dbo.Region (taxAreaId) include(countryId, effdate, filtertypes, expdate);

I created tables and inserted some dummy data. The rewritten query that factors the select countryid as a seperate query successfully produced accurate statistics, and the optimizer selected IX_taxAreaId, which eliminated the sort, as the optimal choice for the query plan. Thus, in my case, I will keep this index instead and delete the other one.
However, your data distribution might differ. Please let me know how this works with your data!

I just join this company few days ago , I did not notice the data type numeric being used . I will check with Developer , also i did not get any implicit conversion alert.

I already have an index with taxAreaId as a leading key , I tried declare the variables as numeric and  did not fix the problem . still getting wrong estimates and sorting

Did you try factor as this 'declare @countryid int = (select countryid from country C where C.name = @p3);'?
